# API for creating Service credentials in IBM COS

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

I am using IBM COS for various bucket operations. While I could find various ways of programmatically performing various bucket operations, I was wondering if there are any ways of programmatically(any sdk or rest apis) creating Service credentials as well as editing the policy for a service id?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are APIs available to access and manage Cloud IAM

Go to the following API docs to review the available APIs:

- [IAM Identity Services API](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/iam-identity-token-api)
- [IAM Access Groups API](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/iam-access-groups)
- [IAM Policy Management API](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/iam-policy-management)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You have partially answered my query. However, I am primarily looking for a way to create Service credentials for IBM Cloud object storage programmatically by using an api.

Comment: As for as I am aware of there’s no API to create credentials programmatically. Because the API and the SDK requires an API Key to get authenticated or authorised with the API before making any GET/POST or other HTTP verb calls

Answer (score 0):

Gaurav,

See this doc page to provision an instance of IBM Cloud Object Storage
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/basics/developers.html#provision-an-instance-of-ibm-cloud-object-storage